# How to make a button Touchable with onTouchListener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a Button that I have tried to make touchable so when I hold it down it moves an ImageView constantly for the amount of time it is held down, but instead, it only moves the ImageView once each time I press it.

```
final ImageView box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.box);
currentX = (int) box.getX();
Button rightarrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
rightarrow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent e) {
        v.performClick();
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.setPressed(true);
            handlerRight.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        currentX += 5;
                        box.setX(currentX);
                        handlerRight.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }, 0);
        } else {
            v.setPressed(false);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` ? It's basically triggered when fingers moves, but it's unlikely the finger will stay still. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I answered it, check it out and tell me if it worked!

Comment: Thanks FonzTech it worked

Answer (score 0):

In that new Thread that you run there, you need to create a while loop that will run while the button is pressed. In that while loop, just move the image. Here is the code:

```
final ImageView box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.box);
currentX = (int) box.getX();
Button rightarrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
rightarrow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent e) {
        v.performClick();
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.setPressed(true);
            handlerRight.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (v.isPressed()){
                        currentX += 5;
                        box.setX(currentX);
                        //handlerRight.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    }
                }
            }, 0);
        } else {
            v.setPressed(false);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note: I'm not sure where that

```
handlerRight.postDelayed(this, 100);
```

is supposed to be because I'm not familiar with it so you just put it. But this is it I hope!

Comment: That redoes the method in handlerRight

Comment: No it isn't a solution